# CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf for public static Lists always fails

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, linq-to-sql, assert

I'm doing a CollectionAssert for two public lists built from linq-to-sql queries. When I do the CollectionAssert for these, it always fails even for a test set which clearly should pass.

I even did a quick test in my code to make sure I'm using the CollectionAssert correctly.

```
        //This always passes
        List<string> testList1 = new List<string>();
        List<string> testList2 = new List<string>();
        testList1.Add("one");
        testList2.Add("two");
        testList2.Add("three");
        testList2.Add("one");
        CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf(testList1, testList2);

        //This always fails 
        CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf(memberOrganizations, member_Dim_Organization, "Error Matching Fields");
```

Any thoughts on how I can correct the syntax of the second assert?  I've attached a screen shot of my debug window. [Debug Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35s5v.jpg)

I define the format of structure of the list in one method

```
namespace DefineStructure
{
    public class Results
    {
        public string OrgID { get; set; }

    }
```

This load the data in a separate

```
namespace Reporting.Member_Dim_Organization.ETL.QA
{
    public class LoadData
    {
    public static cDataContext oMain = new cDataContext();

    public static List<Results> oecMainResults = (from mo in oecMain.MemberOrganizations
                                                  orderby mo.OrgID
                                                  select new Results
                                             {
                                                 OrgID = (mo.OrgID).ToString() }).Take(1).ToList();
```

Then I declare it in my main program

```
namespace Reporting.Main

{
    [Binding]
    public class Member_Dim_OrganizationsSteps
    {
      public static List<Results> memberOrganizations = LoadData.oecMainResults;
      public static List<Results> member_Dim_Organization = LoadData.reportingMasterResults;
```

Does that help clarify?

Thanks for helping an old dog who's trying to learn some new tricks.

Comment: I suspect that `memberOrganizations` and `member_Dim_Organization` are collections of reference types and you have not overridden `Equals` and/or `GetHashCode`.  If they are custom types and you _have_ overridden them then add that implementation to your question.

Comment: I added some more information about how I'm pulling the info. I would love any feedback on my approach.  Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that if the two collections have instances with the same *data* that they are equal, which is not the case by default.  It sounds like you need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on the `Results` class to define "equality".

There are lots of examples out there of defining equality for custom types, most of which involve defining the hash code as a combination of the hash codes of the fields that define equality.

Comment: Awesome advice!  Thank you.I was able to break down the instructions here  http://www.aaronstannard.com/overriding-equality-in-dotnet/   and apply them to my project. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!  It was a huge help.